# Is it possible to compile a grass addon into a commandline app?

Tags: python, grass-gis, command-line, add-ons

As the title says, I'm wondering if it's possible to take the source of a grass add-on and compile it into a commandline app.

Or, alternatively, use the add-on in a python program.

Basically, I don't wish to use grass but I do want the power of an add-on for use in a separate program.

thanks!

Comment: Why? You can call GRASS GIS functionality from outside [Is it possible to use GRASS GIS in Python stand alone scripts?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73639/is-it-possible-to-use-grass-gis-in-python-stand-alone-scripts/73644#73644)

Comment: I was hoping for something that didn't require GRASS. To answer 'why'...the short answer is that when I give a program to somebody, it would be nice to have the option of not having them install grass and the add-ons...some folks have trouble with that stuff.

Comment: But you need all the libraries of GRASS to compile an add-on