# GRASS python API

Tags: python, grass-gis, python-2.7, pygrass

I have `Ubuntu 16.04` 64 bit and `python 2.7.12` on my system. I have installed `GRASS GIS 7` from the `Ubuntu software support` (I thing not is the better choose for install).

Now I want to take GRASS Python API to run standalone Python scripts.

How can I install Python GRASS API(pygrass) to work in the Ubuntu, any idea?

On the Windows must be define paths and work, on LINUX I can't find any tutorial for that.

---

the script test

```
 import os
 import sys
 import subprocess

 grass70='/usr/lib/grass70'

 import grass.script as gscript
```

error :

```
no module name grass.script
```

Comment: Pygrass is integrated in GRASS GIS  ([Working with GRASS without starting it explicitly](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly))

Comment: i cant to import pygrass packages on the python script to start writing code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python/grass/PyGRASS from

1) the Python console of GRASS GIS

[image]

2) the shell of GRASS GIS

[image]

3) from outside, examples for Linux in [Working with GRASS without starting it explicitly](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly) and [Is it possible to use GRASS GIS in Python stand alone scripts?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73639/is-it-possible-to-use-grass-gis-in-python-stand-alone-scripts),and ...

Comment: i want to run outside in Linux but i dont know how to define paths to work with pygrass

Comment: In the reference, the script "Python: GRASS GIS 7 with existing location" explain the solution with Windows, Mac OS X **and**  Linux

Comment: for  the Linux say `grass70 --config path`  `/usr/local/grass-7.0.2svn`.that all ?how to define this path on the Linux ?i am newbie in linux

Comment: for example i define path `/usr/local/grass-7` in the python script but show me error `no module name grass.script`

Comment: Without your script, we can do nothing