# Using GRASS i.segment in Python 3 stand alone script on Windows10

Tags: grass-gis, python-3, osgeo4w, image-segmentation, grass-7.8

I installed GRASS GIS 7.8.1 on Windows 10 using a OSGeo4W.

I would like to use in a stand alone Python 3 script the [`i.segment`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/i.segment.html) GRASS tool.

I saw some related questions (e.g., [Using GRASS GIS in Python standalone scripts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73639) and [call grass modules via python from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130737)) but they all relevant to Python 2.7, or Linux, or some old versions of GRASS or asking you to install GRASS (which is already installed on my computer via OSGeo4W). I don't mind using `subprocess` to exceute the `i.segment` function or to use it "fully" in my script.

Any easy and straightforward way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

**Standalone Python scripts which run GRASS GIS commands**

The "[grass-session](https://github.com/zarch/grass-session)" Python library is an easy way to control GRASS GIS from "outside"-Python. To install the current version, run:

```
pip install grass-session
```

A usage example is also found in the GRASS GIS Wiki, Section:

[Python: GRASS GIS 7 with an external library: grass-session](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly#Python:_GRASS_GIS_7_with_an_external_library:_grass-session)

**Example for usage of i.segment in a Python script**

A Python 3 script (addon) which uses `i.segment` is `i.segment.uspo` ([Python code](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/blob/master/grass7/imagery/i.segment.uspo/i.segment.uspo.py)) which you may look at for inspiration.

**How to write Python GRASS GIS 7 addons**

An alternative to "grass-session" is to write a proper Python GRASS GIS 7 addon and then run it through the [--exec interface](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/grass7.html#batch-jobs-with-the-exec-interface) of the GRASS GIS start program `grass7 --exec ...` like a batch job. The advantage is that GRASS offers a real [parser](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/g.parser.html) to handle flags and parameters which also generates help texts, the GUI instructions, offers JSON output for REST API and much more.

See for example the tutorial "**How to write a Python GRASS GIS 7 addon**" for details: https://github.com/wenzeslaus/python-grass-addon

Comment: I saw it before but I'm not sure how to use it (or if it is complete), can you help me with that? Meaning, it looks like the proper algorithms in Python, should I just copy-past it in my Python IDE (which is Jupyte notebook)? and how do I actually use it -where do I insert the input and parameters? Thanks

Comment: Good point: I have added a link to a useful tutorial.

Comment: Excuse me @markusN, perhaps it can be totally a new question on GIS SE, but can you refer me to any tutorial(s) about the setting&using of a standalone Python GRASS GIS.

Comment: @Taras I have rewritten my answer, hope it is better understandable now.

Comment: Thank you @markusN